# Does merging a branch into both A and B, then merging B into A create issues?

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-merge, git-branch

I have a branch that holds a few small changes, which we merged into the Development branch a couple days ago. Now, we wanted to bring those changes to Master, but we're worried this will become a problem when we merge Development into Master. Can this yield any problems?

To illustrate:

1. Merge A into Dev
2. Merge D, E, F into Dev
3. Merge A into Master
4. Merge Dev into Master

Can something go wrong?

Comment: I've had situations, very rarely, where that caused problems, and the same block of code ended up added twice into the final result, in Master in your scenario. It had to do with having some other changes in the file such that Git didn't "see" it had already put that code in. But in 10 years, I've only faced this twice that I can remember, so it's not something I would worry about.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested a bunch of times with different changes, as long as I don't have any conflicts it seems to work fine... git figures that those changes came from branch A, and doesn't seem to try to re-do them.

As far as I could tell, this works fine

Answer (score 0):

Git is well done, if while performing the merge you have any conflicts, git will tell you.
you can always type the command `git merge --abort` to abort the current merge if something goes wrong or type `git reset <previous commit hash>` to roll back.